# Swift enum inequality

Tags: swift, enums

I'm used to being able to treat `enum`s as numeric values, and thus employ operators like `>`, `<=`, etc. For most enum uses this is probably not that necessary, but one case where it is is states:

```
@objc public enum MyState: Int {
    case Loading = 0
    case Loaded
    case Resolved
    case Processed
}
```

I want to be able to take an instance variable and check this:

```
var state: MyState = ...
if state > .Loaded {
    ...
}
```

But Swift is complaining that it doesn't know what to do. I've declared the enum as being an Int. Is my only option to compare the `rawValue`s? I was hoping to avoid that as it's just going to be really ugly, and Swift gets *sooo* close on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't something along these lines suffice?

```
enum State: Int, Comparable {
    case Loading
    case Loaded
    case Resolved
    case Processed
}

func < (lhs: State, rhs: State) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
}

let state = State.Resolved
state > .Loaded // true
```

Note that only `<` implementation is needed since `enum`s are already equatable...

And in general, comparability of `enums` is independent of their raw values, if any – for example:

```
enum State: Comparable {
    case Good
    case Bad
}

func < (lhs: State, rhs: State) -> Bool {
    return lhs == .Bad && rhs == .Good
}

let state = State.Good
state > .Bad // true
```

**On the second thought**, Swift does allow us to extend `RawRepresentable` protocol with exact effect that @devios is looking for:

```
/// Extends all `RawRepresentable` enums with `Comparable` raw values, 
/// such as `enum E : Int` or `enum E : String`...
///
public func < <E: RawRepresentable where E.RawValue : Comparable> (lhs: E, rhs: E) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
}
```

With this tucked in somewhere in your library of extensions, all you need to do is to explicitly opt in by declaring your type as `Comparable`:

```
enum N: Int, Comparable {
    case Zero, One, Two, Three
}

enum S: String, Comparable {
    case A, B, C, D
}

let n: N = .Two
n > .One // true

let ss: [S] = [.B, .A, .D, .C].sort() // [A, B, C, D]
```

This still allows you to provide a concrete implementation if the generic behaviour is not a perfect fit for a particular type:

```
func < (lhs: S, rhs: S) -> Bool {
    return rhs.hashValue < lhs.hashValue // inverting the ordering
}

let ss: [S] = [.B, .A, .D, .C].sort() // [D, C, B, A]
```

Comment: I guess that's a bit better than using rawValue, but it still feels wrong to have to define my own operators.

Comment: @devios Why?  Just because your enum is backed by a comparable type doesn't mean that the enum itself should necessarily be comparable.

Comment: These are only conformances to a protocol, not custom operators. And it is probably the preferred behaviour, since only you know in what sense your `enum` should be comparable.

Comment: Yes I get that operators are just functions in Swift and can be part of a protocol, so that just takes some getting used to. What feels wrong though is that if `State` is defined as an `Int`, why doesn't it inherit `Comparable` from `Int`?

Comment: Because its comparability may have nothing to do with its raw values. This depends on the semantics of your type.

Comment: Consider `enum Priority: Int { case Unknown = 0, Maximum = 1, High = 2, Medium = 4, Low = 8, Lowest = 16 }`.  Those raw values are probably used for a bit mask or some other thing somewhere where bit position matters, but the inheritance of `Comparable` from `Int` would be *really* wrong here.

Comment: Good example. I can definitely understand the need to have it be overridable. I guess I just wish it also came with a default implementation based on the enum's type. But I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @devios I have updated the answer with a solution much closer in spirit to your question. Sorry I did not come up with this earlier (it was the end of a very long working day...).

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for the alternative solution. That does get me much closer to what I was originally asking for and it's cool to know Swift has the ability to be extended "under the hood" like that. I still wonder why this isn't built in by default but I suppose they have their reasons.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me too much if this was added in a future release of Swift. With Swift 2.2, for example, we now have `Comparable` tuples! At any rate, since the Standard Library is already implementing equality for `RawRepresentable`s with `Equatable` raw value types, I cannot see the danger of similarly conforming to `Comparable` by default...

Comment: In Swift 4 you can write it as a `extension RawRepresentable where RawValue : Comparable { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but there are two ways of going about this, one of which you already mentioned, which is using raw values.

The other way is using the `Comparable` protocol. You can have the enum conform to the protocol and implement the four methods (< is required, >, <= and >= are optional):

```
enum MyState: Int, Comparable {
    ...
}

func < (lhs: MyState, rhs: MyState) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
}

// add other three protocol methods if needed
```

Then you can compare them like integers:

```
if someState > .Loading {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the different logical operators for your enum. No need to use Equatable or Comparable

```
enum State: Int
{    
  case Loading
  case Loaded
  case Resolved
  case Processed
}

func < (lhs: State, rhs: State) -> Bool 
{
  return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
}

func > (lhs: State, rhs: State) -> Bool 
{
  return lhs.rawValue > rhs.rawValue
}
```

Comment: Comparable, not Equatable

Comment: Equatable has nothing to do with the `>` or `<` operators though.  Equatable only specifies the `==` operator is implemented.

Comment: You don't really need to use Comparable or Equatable, just implement the logical function operators with your enum type. :)

Comment: Conforming to Comparable is better for when you need protocol conformance for certain methods.