# Is it possible for a Swift enum with Comparable raw values to synthesize the Comparable protocol implementations automatically?

Tags: swift

Swift can synthesize the `Equatable` implementations for structs and enums automatically. Likewise, I want to make an enum conform to the `Comparable` protocol automatically too.

This is what I did:

```
enum RoyalRank: UInt8 { 
  case emperor = 3
  case king    = 2
  case duke    = 1
}

let e = RoyalRank.emperor
let k = RoyalRank.king
print(e > k)
```

But, of course it won't compile. I got the following error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'RoyalRank' to expected argument type 'UInt8'
print(e > k)
      ^
       .rawValue
```

Is there any way I can do to make an enum conform to the `Comparable` protocol *automatically*?

Comment: By definition, if you need to _do something_ to make it conform to `Comparable`, it is not automatic. Without doing anything, it does not conform to `Comparable`, which means it is not possible for it to automatically conform to `Comparable`.

Comment: @Sweeper The OP means probably a similar behavior like the synthesized `Equatable` conformance of structs. A protocol extension that all enums which are `RawRepresentable` conform to `Comparable` implicitly. But it’s right, Swift doesn’t do it, you have to do it.

Comment: Here is a generic solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296828/1187415 (conditionally extending the RawRepresentable protocol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give a default implementation of the `<` operator for `RawRepresentable` when its associated `RawValue` is `Comparable`:

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue : Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

enum RoyalRank: UInt8, Comparable {
    case emperor = 3
    case king    = 2
    case duke    = 1
}


let e = RoyalRank.emperor
let k = RoyalRank.king
print(e > k)
```

Add `Comparable`to your `enum`, and voilà!

Comment: Is it possible to extend `RawRepresentable` and let it conform to `Comparable` 
_automatically_ whenever `RawValue` is `Comparable`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you cannot have it automatically, you'll always have to declare a type `Comparable`. The only benefit is that you won't have to write the any other line of code.